# Wrong pattern when using regexp w/ mysql ..?

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a mysql table that's pretty simple & small.

```
award_id bigint(11) primary key auto_inc  
award_receip varchar(160) NULL  
date_receip DATETIME NOT NULL
```

When I make the following query, I don't get the expected results.

```
SELECT * FROM awards WHERE award_id REGEXP '("1|6|3")'
```

Only `award_id` 6 is in the result set. 
The primary keys are all consecutive into the thousands.

What's the error in my pattern that prevents `award id` 1 & `award id` 3 from being displayed in the results ?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be using a regex at all.  `award_id` is `BIGINT`, so use `IN`:

```
SELECT * FROM awards WHERE award_id IN (1,6,3);
```

Just for completeness, if one were sadistic enough to use a regex, two of many possible patterns would be:

```
SELECT * FROM awards WHERE award_id RLIKE '^(1|6|3)$';
SELECT * FROM awards WHERE (award_id LIKE '1' OR award_id LIKE '6' OR award_id LIKE '3');
```

But yeah, don't use those, just use `IN`.

Comment: much faster method i assume ... great solution. Thank you.